# Libraries building on private computer

Tags: compilation

I have question about libriaries compiling. I'm really new to this topic and I have noob question. I google about it but I cant find good information and I really dont know what to search honestly. I try to compile ffmpeg library for Android. I read about it and everywhere peaples says that I need to download source and compile it on my computer. My question is why I need to compile it by myself? Cant someone just cmpile it and then share it via internet? Why I necessarily need to compile it by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is why I need to compile it by myself? Cant someone just
>   cmpile it and then share it via internet? Why I necessarily need to
>   compile it by myself?

There's actually so many way to build ffmpeg for different kind of system that you might as well prefer to compile it these libraries yourself.

Why, it has to be that way? Well, it seem that people are just lazy to share those for your specific system, but maybe you can make a request to this [website](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), so it can provide up-to-date build for android as well.